# Gmail fetching mails from Sent items as well

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have the following code to connect to an inbox of a mail server:

```
Store popStore = popSession.getStore("pop3");
popStore.connect(address, userName, password);
Folder  inboxFolder = popStore.getFolder("Inbox");
```

Post this i check for new mails. Now when I connect to Gmail, I am getting mails from Sent Items as well when actually it is supposed to be only from the Inbox folder. With Yahoo this is working fine.

Any Idea what can be causing this issue in Gmail?

Edit: I have tried with INBOX as well and the result is the same

Comment: try "INBOX".. and i guess the items which you are referring to "Sent Mail" may be replies from the reciptents, which also have the same subject line with a preceding "RE : "..

Comment: Will try with INBOX. And no, I had verified about the scenario you described by sending new mails with unique subjects from the account I am downloading

Comment: @rajesh : Are you showing the real code? Why not paste more (not)working example?

Answer (score 3):

Following is a code snippet. When I checked with gmail, there is no overlap between inbox and sent mail.  (This should have been a comment, posting as answer for formatting)

```
javax.mail.Folder[] folders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
for (javax.mail.Folder folder : folders) {
    if ((folder.getType() & javax.mail.Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES) != 0) {
        if (folder.getFullName().equalsIgnoreCase("[Gmail]/Sent Mail") 
                || folder.getFullName().equalsIgnoreCase("Inbox")) {
            System.out.println(folder.getFullName() + ": " + folder.getMessageCount());
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            for (Message m : folder.getMessages(
                               folder.getMessageCount() - 5, 
                               folder.getMessageCount())) {
                System.out.println("m.getSubject() = " + m.getSubject());
            }
            folder.close(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for ( Message m: folder.getMessages( folder.getMessageCount()-5, folder.getMessageCount())) `  Are you checking for only 5 messages?

Answer (score 3):

firstly try this

```
Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
folder = folder.getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting issue. I did a little research and found [this post](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/16418) in which Google says:

> When you enable POP, all messages are downloaded to your client, except for Spam, Trash, and Chats. If you don't want messages that you send from the web interface downloaded to your mail client's inbox, we suggest creating a filter within your client.

To create a filter by sender, you can do this:

```
String filter = "Not([SenderEmailAddress] = 'XXXXX@gmail.com')";
Items inboxItems = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict(filter);
```

where `XXXXX@gmail.com` is your email address. This filter will give you only the items which are sent by someone other than yourself. Additionally, the `Restrict` method can be replaced with `Find`, but `Restrict` will be much faster for larger datasets.

Comment: Interesting find. But I believe this labeling is happening only for mails to which I have replied. There are some mails which are newly composed. They dont have the Inbox labelling

Comment: All the same, if any mail sent by you have the `Inbox` label, this filter will fix it. I believe this is caused by how Google handles conversation view of emails.

Comment: But my issue is with mails not having Inbox labels. please see my comment to Armaan's answer below

Comment: tried turning the conversation mode off. but still issue persists :-) :-(

Comment: @rajesh Try this out.

Comment: you missed a link or something?

Comment: @rajesh Yeah. Was trying to solve it through gmail, but a different wording of the same search came up with this. So, sorry it seems it must be done client side.

Answer (score 2):

when you communicate through mail using reply or reply to all in gmail it will considered as inbox mail. Because it is conversation view. so that your sent mail is also an inbox mail. so you will get that mails in your messages.

Read [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?hl=en) official google answer.

Comment: But I am getting issues in a newly composed messages as well, not just replies

Comment: If you compose a message, and the recipient replies to that message, then Google would move your original message to the inbox for conversation view. I'm not sure why you would see this on a new message *without* a reply.

Comment: There is no recipient replies yet for those and no Inbox labelling. I did have those scenarios which I understand but there is an issue when the mail is composed newly and sent and is not replied back to